# Hold values in request scope in MVC 3 without IOC?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i hold values in http request scope without using IOC ?

Quick answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put them into `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items`

[Via MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Gets a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share data between an IHttpModule interface and an IHttpHandler interface during an HTTP request.